# is there any way to automatically import modules in eslint or vscode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, auto-import

so I created a `consoledata.ts` file to log whatever I pass in it as an argument like so:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
export default function ConsoleData(props: any) {
  console.log(props);
}
```

now using the VSCode search icon, I changed every `console.log` in my code to `consoleData` since it'll probably take me all day to change them one by one.
now my issue is, the `consoleData` module is not imported. is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to auto import in VSCode. The first way is using quick fix. If you are on MacOS, you can do `Cmd + .` to open the quick fix dialog and then you import the module.

The second option is to use auto import suggestions. They show suggestions as you type. If you are on MacOS, select the function/class you want to import and then you can do `Ctrl + Space` to open the auto import suggestions dialog.

Comment: I understand this. but what I'm asking is a way to import into all files without opening them one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) plugin to identify unresolved imports, which can be fixed by IDE's fix options or `--fix` flag for eslint. If you use aliases, check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-custom-alias) one as well.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)